# Slide up element on hover

Tags: jquery

Take a look at http://www.shopvcf.com/blog/?page_id=56

I need the area with the red heart to slide up which I have done with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.bottomwrap').on({
        'mouseenter': function () {
            $(this).animate({
                bottom: 20
            });
        },
        'mouseleave': function () {
            $(this).animate({
                bottom: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Issue is I would like it to slide up when entering into the box with the content, not just the bottomwrap.

I would also like to hide the   at the same time which will show the image in the background.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: He posted what he already tried.

Comment: Try adding the events to the entire box, not just `bottomwrap`.

Comment: I noticed an issue on your page.  You have multiple elements with ID `postwrap`.  Don't do that.  IDs should be unique, make that a class.

Comment: Your `containloop` is also an id with multiple divs.

Comment: The reason for multiple postwraps is because this is wordpress with three loops. It just surrounds some text in each loop. Same with the contain loop.

Comment: @user1525766: That doesn't mean that they should all have the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you'll want to do is set the queue for animate to false and set a duration. Else, if a user hovers over the screen back and forth quickly every thing continues to move around.

Check out http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for more details, but it would look like so:

As for your issue. I would first change the **id**'s of all the set "jpgoverlay" - setting it to a class name - if an option. Then the below code should do the trick. Having an ID with a non-unique name might cause you some pain later.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('div.jpgoverlay').on({
         'mouseenter': function() {
         $(this).animate({ bottom: 20 },{queue:false,duration:400});
    },
     'mouseleave': function() {
         $(this).animate({ bottom: 0 },{queue:false,duration:400});
     }
    });
});
```